# C# regex.escape unexpected behavior when processing "."

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Hey I have an issue with Regex.Escape I'm trying to feed it an Email from TextBox Controll. The function recieves "test@test.test". What I expect to get is this `"test@test\.test"` Regex.Escape escapes the dot character. Hovever what I get instead is `"test@test\\.test"` which is very confusing. I plan on handing that string down to an SQL query and I'm worried abut users misbehaving.

```
holder.address = Regex.Escape(EmailAddressInput.Text);
```

This is how I assign resulting string to field in holder class.
I have been researching this problem on my own but most sources (including MSDN) suggest to prefix the dot ("the special character") with one backslash.
As it is right now backslash escapes backslash and result is a badly formatted email address.

Comment: Where do you see the `"test@test\\.test"` - in the pop up that appears after hovering the cursor over the string in VS after regex escaping? Then it is OK, there is 1 escape symbol.

Comment: I'm using visual studio I have set up a breakpoint on the line after email address asignment. During debug in Locals holder.address I see it has value of "test@test\\.test"

Comment: `var s = "test@test\\.test";` means the `s` holds the `test@test\.test` string. Your issue does not exist. There is a single backslash. Click the mahnifier button on the right - you will see that in the *Text Visualizer*.

Comment: I removed `email` and `regex` tags as those are not the subject of the question.

Comment: Is `EmailAddressInput` supposed to accept a pattern as input? You shouldn't be escaping the string to be matched against--only a string that you intend to use as a pattern.

Comment: No. `EmailAddressInput` is textbox controll. It takes input from user which when not escaped correctly can allow for bad behavior. for example if user inputs something like `test@test.test" ; DROP DATABASE ;` which I would like to avoid. If user tries something like this when string is properly escaped the result will be a wierd field in an email record and not catastrophic damage to database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var s = "test@test\\.test";` means the `s` holds the `test@test\.test` string. Your issue does not exist. There is a single backslash. Click the magnifier button on the right - you will see that in the *Text Visualizer*.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I downvoted you because of that anti-downvoting note in the post really distracted from the answer. I suggest you try to refrain from community commentary in your answers and stick to answering the question.

Comment: It is somewhat important to note that the reason the debugger is doing is is that it too is trying to escape the string to be legal C# syntax. So you have a double escape scenario here.

Comment: sorry I'm still a bit new to this I propably misclicked and wanted to reward you with an upvote.

Comment: @Jahith: No, Jahith, it is all right. Just some people downvote for fun and love losing points. Let's.

Answer (score 0):

Regex has to have \\ because its escaping the \

the string itself actually only has one \ in it.

Comment: but I'm feeding it "test@test.test" there are no \ there.

Comment: but you asked it to escape characters so it found . and escaped it, with \ but it puts in \\ because the \ is litteral

Comment: @Jahith: Your question was confusing before I edited it - it looked like you just wanted "test@test.test".

Comment: I'm sorry. Debugger trew me off as it was displaying dubble backslash instead of a single one that I expected.

Comment: yep, hence my explaination.. it needs to

Comment: No, regex doesn't need to escape the backslash, the backslash is there to escape the *dot*. The double backslash is something completely different, the debugger is showing two backslashes because it *too* tries to escape the string to be legal C# syntax. There is only one backslash in the string after asking regex to escape it, and that is escaping the dot.